# DirectoryEntry not returning group members in .NET but works in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, directoryentry

I'm trying to build a list of all the local groups on a machine and all the users in each of those groups.

This is the code I'm using

```
foreach (string group in groups)
{
    try
    {
        using (DirectoryEntry computerGroupEntry = new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("WinNT://{0}/{1},group", Environment.MachineName, group)))
        {
            foreach (object userG in (IEnumerable)computerGroupEntry.Invoke("Members"))
            {
                DirectoryEntry user = new DirectoryEntry(userG);
                users.Add(group, user.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    { }
}
```

This works just fine in ASP.NET on an IIS 8.1 server.

I'm trying to convert this into an command line executable file using Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.6.1 using C# but it won't compile and even after compiling it won't find the group members.

1. When I paste the same code into Visual Studio C# project it gives me error for `foreach (object userG in (IEnumerable)computerGroupEntry.Invoke("Members"))`
   with an error message

   > Error CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'IEnumerable' because 'IEnumerable' does not contain a public instance definition for 'GetEnumerator'
2. If I change the line to `foreach (object userG in computerGroupEntry.Properties["Members"])` it compiles but at run time it doesn't find any property `Members

So why is the code working on ASP.NET but the C# executable not seeing any user `Members` for the groups (both running on the same machine)?

Also if anyone has an idea why it's throwing an error with the IEnumerable statement in .NET but working in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted worked for me as-is in console application(which is an executable) with targeted .NET framework 4.6.1 in VS 2019.
Please verify if the below references are present.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

`(IEnumerable)computerGroupEntry.Invoke("Members")` needs `System.Collections`

I provided the group "Administrators" and I was able to retrieve "wsAdmin", "Domain Admins"

Comment: Amazingly (and frustratingly) `System.Collections` was the issue for both. I don't get it why VS can't be more direct instead of such a cryptic error

Comment: I'm curious which `IEnumerable` it was resolving to when you didn't have that `using` there. If you hover over `IEnumerable` in your code, it will tell you the full class name including the namespace.

Comment: @GabrielLuci : 
IEnumerable belongs to System.Collections.
IEnumerable<T> belongs to System.Collections.Generic.

The System.Collections.Generic namespace contains interfaces and classes that define generic collections. For more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @rboy : if possible, try to get VS 2019, it will suggest you, as a potential fix, to add the required namespace when you place the cursor on the red squiggly.

Comment: @IamP VS 2017 will do that too. The fact that it did not (and instead gave the error it did) tells me that it was using a different IEnumerable.